# create list with element names in variable in R

Tags: r

How can I get from this:

```
names <- c("a", "b")
values <- c(1, 2)
```

To This:

```
list(
     list("a" = 1)
    ,list("b" = 2)
    )
```

I know this do not works:

```
ll <- list()
for(n in 1:length(names)){
  ll <- append(ll, list(names[n] = values[[n]]))
}
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use

```
list(setNames(as.list(values), names))
```